# Sum of primes, Conundrum

Tags: c#, primes

So after pulling my hair out for 30 minutes, I have decided to come to SO for some help on this problem:

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
>
> Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

Now, I don't want to know *how* to do the problem - that's easy - and *especially not* the answer. I would like to know why my code isn't giving me the correct answer when I run it (C#):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Euler010 {
    public static bool isPrime(Int64 n) {
        if (n <= 1)
            return false;
        if (n < 4)
            return true;
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            return false;
        if (n < 9)
            return true;
        if (n % 3 == 0)
            return false;

        Int64 r = (Int64)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt((double)n));
        Int64 f = 5;
        while (f <= 4) {
            if (n % f == 0)
                return false;
            if (n % (f + 2) == 0)
                return false;
            f += 6;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void Main() {
        Int64 sum = 2;
        for (Int64 n = 3; n <= 2000000; n+=2) {
            if (isPrime(n)) {
                sum += n;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When run to `n <= 10`, it outputs `17`, like it should. When run to anything that's easy to compute by hand, it outputs the correct answer (like `n <= 20` -> `77`).

However, when I run this, it outputs `666667333337` which is wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really mean "Int64 f=5; while (f<=4) {" ?  That seems like a while loop that isn't going to do anything.

Comment: FYI, there are lots of neat shortcuts when testing numbers for primes.  One that I like is this -- after 2 and 3, you only need to check numbers having the form: (6n -1) and (6n +1), starting with n=1.

Comment: Why not calculate it directly? Let's see, the sum of all integers is n * (n + 1) / 2...subtract composite multiples of two... n(n+1)/(2p)-p...um.... I'll leave the rest as an excersize. :-)

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Very different [from mine(on github)](https://github.com/thegiddygeek/ProjectEuler_CSharp/blob/master/ProjectEuler/Problems/Problem10.cs), I used the [sieve of eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_eratosthenes) as the basis for finding all primes. [Blogged about it here](http://gideondsouza.com/blog/a-superfast-way-to-search-for-prime-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Int64 f = 5;
        while (f <= 4) {
```

Maybe I'm missing something here but these two lines don't seem to make sense. I'm fairly certain that the code posted above will never execute the body of the `while` loop.

Perhaps you meant to check if `f` is less than the square root of `r`?

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the variable r in your loop, I assume you probably want to loop while f<=r?

Answer (score 1):

Not what you are looking for, but you should probably use something like [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to generate your primes.

Answer (score 0):

Plus the existing tests catch all non-primes below 20 (divisible by 2, 3, etc).